# Posting a question on "Python security when reading from and writing to local files"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is the question below most appropriate for *Stack Overflow* or *another Stack Exchange site*?

- Since the **context** of the question is about Python software, *Super User would seem appropriate*: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic (However after asking the question there, it has been placed on hold: *[Python security when reading from and writing to local files](https://superuser.com/questions/1404613/python-security-when-reading-from-and-writing-to-local-files)*)
- Since the **specific part** of the question has Python code, *Stack Overflow would seem appropriate*

**In case I decide to post it on *Stack Overflow*, would you suggest any improvements?**

---

Given a standard installation of Python 3.6 on Windows 7, with the code below in a Jupyter Notebook or a Python script:

- Will any of the contents of `data.csv` be temporarily saved outside of the `C:/data` folder during any of the three steps below?
- If any temporary files are stored outside of this folder, would it be possible for any other application to read them and decipher the contents?
- Does the answer depend on any other factors, i.e. if the contents of `data.csv` are too large to fit in memory?
- If the answer to either of the first two questions is positive, which steps could be taken to avoid this?

> `import pandas as pd import os`
> `path='C:/data'`
> `os.chdir(path)`
>
> `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') # step 1`
>
> `#data manipulation (any transformations on df) # step 2`
>
> `df.to_csv(index=False) # step 3`

Tags for this question:

- windows-7
- python
- pandas
- anaconda
- jupyter-notebook

Comment: Python is considered a programming language, which is explicitly off-topic on Super User. The on-topic questions about it on Super User are nearly exclusively about setting up Python, configuring it, and issues due to issues with the setup. This sounds on-topic on SO, but I'd wait with posting it until someone experienced in the Python tag comes along and gives you some feedback.

Comment: Tagging it with [tag:pandas] sounds appropriate since the question is actually about the internal behavior of the pandas load/store methods.

Comment: @ErikA, thanks that's a clear distinction regarding Python. I'll wait for a few more comments about how to improve it for SO.

Comment: For the “bigger than memory” question, the answer is yes and is independent of programming language or application: the swap file. Your OS will protect it from naive snooping, but lots of very clever and motivated people work on building non-naive snoopers.

Comment: Consider using slightly less formatting in your posts. Your first bullet point is mostly bold or italics, which means multiple emphasis, which can make for some confusion. The names of sites need not be in italics either.